# SQL Grouping Acct Numbers and Getting Subtotals and Grand Total

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

This query...

```
SELECT ACTNO,SUM(PLAN) AS 'TOTAL PLAN', SUM(FORECAST) AS 'TOTAL FORECAST'
FROM   COST_CENTER
GROUP BY ACTNO
```

I get the following results:

```
ACTNO  | TOTAL PLAN | TOTAL FORECAST
100    | 12000      | 20000         
101    | 12000      | 20000         
200    | 1000       | 1500         
201    | 1200       | 2000          
202    |  900       | 1500         
203    |  700       | 1500         
220    | 1500       | 3500         
300    | 1200       | 2000         
301    | 1000       | 3000
```

I need to group together certain accounts, get those groups' subtotals, and then add all the subtotals up for a grand total.

The desired result would be something like:

```
ACTNO  | TOTAL PLAN | TOTAL FORECAST
100    | 12000      | 20000         
101    | 12000      | 20000 
         24000        40000        
200    | 1000       | 1500         
201    | 1200       | 2000          
202    |  900       | 1500         
203    |  700       | 1500 
         3800         6500
220    | 1500       | 3500         
300    | 1200       | 2000         
301    | 1000       | 3000 
         3700         8500
Total   31500        55000
```

This gets me somewhat close, but not quite in the format I'd like.

```
SELECT ACTNO, SUM(PLAN), SUM(FORECAST)
FROM     COST_CENTER
WHERE  (ACTNO IN ('100','101'))
GROUP BY ACTNO WITH ROLLUP
...

ACTNO  |            | 
NULL   | 24000      | 40000
100    | 12000      | 20000         
101    | 12000      | 20000
```

Thanks for the time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more control with grouping sets:

```
SELECT ACTNO, grp, SUM(PLAN), SUM(FORECAST)
FROM (SELECT cc.*,
             (CASE WHEN ACTNO IN ('100', '101') THEN 1
                   WHEN ACTNO IN ('200', '201', '202', '203') THEN 2
                   WHEN ACTNO IN ('220', '300', '301') THEN 3
              END) as grp
      FROM COST_CENTER cc
     ) cc
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (ACTNO, grp), (grp), ());
```

You can probably remove `grp` from the `SELECT` . . . I have never used `GROUPING SETS` without including the column, though.

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. Just curious, is there any way to fill the NULLs and keep them in the right order?

Comment: You can fill the `NULL`s by using `COALESCE()` (not really recommended but easier for the lazy) or using the `GROUPING()` function.  The right order is a bit trickier, if you don't want the rows in the default order.