# mySQL inner counts are killing my query performance

Tags: mysql

SELECT DISTINCT cl.client, cl.clientUNIQUE, (SELECT COUNT(taskUNIQUE) AS countTasks FROM tasks WHERE state='NF' AND clientUNIQUE=cl.clientUNIQUE AND status='V') AS ActiveTasks, (SELECT COUNT(projectUNIQUE) FROM projects WHERE status='V' AND state!='end' AND clientUNIQUE=cl.clientUNIQUE) AS ActiveProjects FROM clients AS cl LEFT JOIN tasks AS tsk ON cl.clientUNIQUE=tsk.clientUNIQUE WHERE cl.status='V' AND cl.accountUNIQUE='[client]0E2D3B21D716BB71A83331558656EC47' ORDER BY ActiveTasks DESC LIMIT 10

```
This query takes about 5 second to run. Too many counts? Any suggestion to improve performance?
```

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449872/sql-grouping-acct-numbers-and-getting-subtotals-and-grand-total) from a new user and now look at yours. Please put more effort in yours.

Comment: What is your schema? What are your indexes?

Comment: @juergen d: query result is ok, its just taking too long.

Comment: @kmoser: just using index on the auto increment column

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is embarrassing, but I didn't create any index. Thanks kmoser for the question that guided me to the answer.